# ListView Item filled with Color

Tags: vb.net, listview

I need Help with my ListView.

I have Add Items with :

```
Dim str(4) As String
Dim itm As ListViewItem


str(0) = game
str(1) = name
str(2) = coder
str(3) = lastupdated
str(4) = status
If str(4) = "1" Then
    str(4) = "Patched"



Else
    str(4) = "Working"
End If
itm = New ListViewItem(str)

Form2.GameList2.Items.Add(itm)
```

How can make Items with Text "Patched" Red Text and "Working" Green

Comment: What have you tried, this is not even trying to do anything with color.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you done *any* research such as reading some of the many posts here?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - this is not a code writing service.

Comment: f GameList2.Items(13).SubItems(2).Text.Contains("Patched") Then
            GameList2.Items(13).ForeColor = Color.Maroon
        End If

Comment: You must set the ListViewItem.UsesItemStyleForSubItems property to False and use the ListViewItem.SubItems(index).BackColor and ForeColor to colorize it.

Comment: How you mean ? Only this who have there words?

Comment: I found now the issue !  test.ForeColor = Color.Red and Dim test As New ListViewItem(str)